# Write into WIN32 resource file

Tags: c++, windows, resources

I am writing a GUI application in C++ on Windows 10. I know how to incorporate a data file into the .exe file by using [Windows Resources](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Resource_Script_Reference), and how to read from this file at runtime. In the C++ code, I do:

```
char* bytes;
HMODULE hModule;
HRSRC hResource;
HGLOBAL hMemory;
DWORD dwSize;
LPVOID lpAddress;
LPCWSTR resource_id;
wstring temp;

temp = wstring("my_resource_file");

resource_id = (temp.c_str());

hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
hResource = FindResource(hModule, resource_id, L"DATA");

if (hResource != NULL) {
    //the resource has been found

    hMemory = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
    dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
    lpAddress = LockResource(hMemory);

    bytes = new char[dwSize];
    memcpy(bytes, lpAddress, dwSize);
    value = new istringstream(bytes);

}
```

And in the .rc file I have

```
my_resource_file DATA "my_file.dat"
```

How may I write into the my_resource_file ? I would like to write into it at runtime, in such a way that the next way I run the .exe file and load my_resource_file, I will read the modified data.

Comment: Take a look at the [UpdateResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-updateresourcea) function.

Comment: So this is possible ?!

Comment: Yes in principle. But an EXE file cannot update itself; it's read-only while it's running (and of course it can't do anything while it isn't running). Also, if and when you distribute your program commercially, you would want to sign it; and modifying the EXE would break the signature. All things considered, I would suggest you just store your data in a file on disk.

Comment: I would like to set a counter of the number of times the exe file has been opened , in order to prompt a message when this number of times reaches 10, without writing anywhere else than in the exe file itself. That is why I wanted to write this information in the exe file as a resource. How can I do that ?